# NullReferenceException with StartCoroutine()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2015, nullreferenceexception

I made coroutine which will do my loading in game but every time i click play button I get NullReferenceException on line: StartCoroutine(LoadNewScene());

Here is my full code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Loading : MonoBehaviour
{

    private bool LoadScene = false;

    [SerializeField]
    private int scene = 0;
    [SerializeField]
    private Text LoadingText;
    [SerializeField]
    private Text TipText;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (LoadScene == true)
        {
            scene++;
        }
    }

    public void Load()
    {
        LoadScene = true;
        //LoadingText.color = new Color(LoadingText.color.r, LoadingText.color.g, LoadingText.color.b, Mathf.PingPong(Time.time, 1));
        StartCoroutine(LoadNewScene()); //here is my error
    }

    IEnumerator LoadNewScene() // my coroutine
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);

        AsyncOperation async = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(scene);

        while (!async.isDone)
        {
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But i need answer in my situation -_-

Comment: Consider that `GameObject` witch started that coroutine will be destroyed when new level loaded.

Comment: @PawełMarecki so i need to keep this object on next level?

Comment: Yes, thats one of possible solutions, i think the simplest one. You can use e.g `DontDestroyOnLoad`.

Comment: _"But i need answer in my situation"_ The best answer is "learn to use your debugging tools".  _Everyone_ hits this problem, the best course of action is to trace through your code to find why it's not what you think it should be.

Comment: @JamesThorpe how can i learn to use them, im new to c#

Comment: @VitoGaming The duplicate question goes through how to resolve this in excruciating detail. I'd suggest you start there.

Comment: @VitoGaming In all honesty, probably by starting with something simpler than unity.  There's _lots_ of info out there, perhaps start with some simple console applications so you get to know your tools.

Comment: Fixed it myself :D